# Mocking multiple named exports in jest.mock(moduleName, factory) factory function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, babel-jest

I've been using Jest in a small project, and am having trouble with Jest mocks. I have a utility file that exports named custom error constructor functions. I need to mock those functions in my test file. I don't want to use the manual mocking technique shown in the Jest documentation (i.e., putting a mock file in `__mocks__`), but rather I want to define the mocks in the test file. I am trying something like this in my test file:

```
const errorMock = () => {
  return {
    configNotFoundError: jest.fn(() => new Error()),
    invalidJSONError: () => jest.fn(() => new Error()),
  }
};

jest.mock('./error', errorMock);

const { configNotFoundError, invalidJSONError } = require('./error');
```

But I get the following error:

```
babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The second argument of `jest.mock` 
must be an inline function.
```

Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem with named exports recently.
according to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html), `jest.mock` calls are hoisted to the top of the test and are subsequently executed before you define `errorMock`.  Functions seem to be hoisted above these calls. Try:

```
function errorMock() {
  return {
    configNotFoundError: jest.fn(() => new Error()),
    invalidJSONError: () => jest.fn(() => new Error()),
  }
};

jest.mock('./error', errorMock);

const { configNotFoundError, invalidJSONError } = require('./error');
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Lesbaa, great answer!

Comment: This can be dangerous as you are easily tempted to use outside context in your function. Best to keep it inline, as recommended by the error.